# Are questions about touch rugby on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Touch rugby is a sport widely played in New Zealand and Australia.

It is similar to rugby league, except that instead of tackling, the player with the ball is touched.

However, to the best of my knowledge, there doesn't seem to be an organisation of touch rugby or even official rules.

**Are questions about touch rugby on topic**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, a blatant "yes". Touch rugby is a perfectly good sport.

Comment: Touch rugby questions are on topic. So might it be, by lack of dissent.

Comment: @MathiasFoster Run with it. It's more likely that we point out what is off-topic more so than what is on-topic. If we have no problem with `touch-rugby`, then go for it.

Comment: "Run with it." I presume "it" is the ball in that sentence :-)

Comment: @PhilipKendall Pun not intended, or was it? ;)